# Qual a razão do erro "This view is not constrained ...", em ConstraintLayout?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

Qual é a razão deste erro?

> This view is not constrained, it only has designtime positions, so it will jump to (0,0) unless you add constraints

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.pedrogouveia.myapplication.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:autoSizeStepGranularity="?android:attr/dialogPreferredPadding"
        android:text="SIGN UP"
        android:textColor="#54C571"
        android:textSize="25dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="16dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="16dp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/Primeiro Nome"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:text="Primeiro Nome"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="16dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="97dp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:text="Apelido"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="16dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="178dp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:text="e-mail"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="16dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="261dp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:text="password"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="16dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="347dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="266dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="411dp" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: @PedroGouveia , se o processador reclamou disso, isso significa que não teve erro sintático, apenas essa alerta semântico

Comment: A minha resposta respondeu suas dúvidas? Há algo que necessite de melhor explicação?

Comment: Como devo fazer para que no relative layout, ela fique em baixo e nao suba? É que nao sei porque la diz que é relativeLayout

Comment: Esta a referir-se a quê? Aqui não tem nenhum RelativeLayout.

Comment: Como corrigir esse erro num relative layout mesmo que nao tenha aqui,o erro de o botão sair do lugar quando meto puxa o keyboard

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This view is not constrained, it only has designtime positions, so it will jump to (0,0) unless you add constraints.

Esse aviso indica que as *views* não declaram restrições(*constraints*) suficientes de forma a poderem ser posicionadas.

Ou seja, as *views* não indicam como devem ser posicionadas em relação umas às outras ou em relação ao seu *layout* "pai". Elas serão posicionadas nas coordenadas (0,0).

Num ConstraintLayout cada *view* deve declarar pelo menos uma restrição horizontal e uma vertical. Cada restrição representa uma ligação ou alinhamento para outra *view*, *layout* "pai" ou uma orientação.
Cada restrição define a posição da vista ao longo do eixo vertical ou horizontal.

O editor de *layouts* do Android Studio, para mostrar o *layout* de forma consistente, automaticamente acrescenta atributos de restrição com valores absolutos, usando o *namespace tools*.
No entanto eles não são usados em tempo de execução.

Esses atributos são:

```
tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="valor"
tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="valor"
```

Tem de adicionar restrições de forma a que as *views* possam ser posicionadas sem a necessidade do editor acrescentar esses atributos.

Para mais informações sobre como usar o ConstraintLayout veja:

- [ConstraintLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintLayout.html).
- [Build a Responsive UI with ConstraintLayout](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/index.html#constraints-overview).